# How to add a new domain in cpanel

Tags: dns, cpanel, godaddy-api

When I trying to add the new domain on addon domains then "Your addon domain limit of 0 addon domains has been reached. The addon domain Xyz .com was not added." this message is showing.

So how can I add a new domain in the Cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of your account's package limits. You'll need to discuss the features your account should have with your provider.